# How can I change the items of an EnumProperty dynamically through draw?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have those two `EnumProperty`:

```
fu3dm_model_gender : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Gender", description="Choose model's gender.", items= [('OP1', "Male", ""), ('OP2', "Female", "")])    
fu3dm_model_head : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Head", description="Choose model's head.", items= [('OP1', "Generic Male", ""), ('OP2', "Something", "")])
```

And I want to do this:

If `fu3dm_model_gender` is `OP1` then `fu3dm_model_head` items to be like this `items= [('OP1', "Generic Male", ""), ('OP2', "Something", "")]`. Else if `fu3dm_model_gender` is `OP2` then `fu3dm_model_head` items to be like this `items= [('OP1', "Generic Female", ""), ('OP2', "Something Else", "")]`.

Here is my code:

```
class fu3dm_WM_OT_Model_Prefs_Operator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.fu3dm_model_prefs"
    bl_label = "Model Preferences"
    bl_description = "Sets model's preferences"

    fu3dm_model_gender : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Gender", description="Choose model's gender.", items= [('OP1', "Male", ""), ('OP2', "Female", "")])
    fu3dm_model_head : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Head", description="Choose model's head.", items= [('OP1', "Generic Male", ""), ('OP2', "Something", "")])

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
        bpy.ops.wm.fu3dm_model_prefs('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_gender")
        if self.fu3dm_model_gender == 'OP1':
            # Change "fu3dm_model_head" to "Generic Male" and "Something"
        elif self.fu3dm_model_gender == 'OP2':
            # Change "fu3dm_model_head" to "Generic Female" and "Something Else"
        layout.prop(self, "fu3dm_model_head")

    def execute(self, context):
        pass
        return {"FINISHED"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use EnumProperty callback:

[Property Definitions (bpy.props) — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html?highlight=enumproperty#bpy.props.EnumProperty)

Basically blender will call the function in following way:

```
list_tuple_callback(scene, context)
```

The return of your function should look similar with the original item `List[(identifier, name, description, icon, number), ...]`.